# Why is my .env undefined and why is it not working?

Tags: node.js, json, express, environment-variables, dotenv

I am having issue with the last 10 lines of code where I am working with a .env. I have already added my .env file with the MESSAGE_STYLE=uppercase.

However, when starting the local server with npm start, i get the lower case version of my "hello json" message, not the upper case version.

It also says my secret.env file in root is there and says A now, isntead of U, as undefined, idk what I did differently, however, I am still getting my output as :
{
"message": "Hello json"
}

not what i am expecting to be:

{
"message": "Hello json"
}

**Input:**

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
require('dotenv').config();



app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"))


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile (__dirname + "/views/index.html");

})

app.get ("/json", (req, res) => {
    if ( process.env["MESSAGE_STYLE"] == "uppercase"){
        res.json({"mesage": "HELLO JSON"});
    } else {
         res.json({"message": "Hello json"});
    }
})

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: my expected output is supposed to all be uppercase not lowercase. so I need it to say, HELLO JSON, not hello json.

Comment: i just realized i needed to make the .env file without naming it in order for hte process.env to work, other wise I would have needed to specifically call it or import it from the .env file that was named "secret" omg i got it haha wow

Answer (score 1):

According to the [dotenv documentation](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#config), the environment variables are loaded from the `.env` file by default. If you want to load them from a custom `secret.env` file, you need to configure it:

```js
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'secret.env' })
```

Comment: omg yes this worked. I did not realize i needed to do this. In the course it never even mentions this. It just has me created a .env file in root directory and use process.env to call it, but never works. idk how others made it work without specifically importing it. I know in python you import from other files using inheritance so it makes sense doing this. thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Can you change the order of the import?

So instead of having

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
require('dotenv').config();
```

You have to do

```
require('dotenv').config(); // Make sure this is on the first line of your file
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
```

If it's not helping you can also use the debug mode for `dotenv`

```
require('dotenv').config({ debug: true });
```

Or you can also debug using:

```
console.log(require('dotenv').config())
```

Comment: this all worked thank you :)

Comment: I am now getting an error message via freecodecamp saying, The response of the endpoint /json should change according to the environment variable MESSAGE_STYLE. why would this happen?

Comment: hey @DillonTierney! not sure about the context here, are you making any API call to Frecodecamp?